# Do crystal report alignment depend on printers, what happens if there is no printer installed in system?

Tags: crystal-reports-2008

In our application we export RPT to PDF format using java code. The PDF's are generated correctly in most of our environments. But currently we got a new environment and in this environment some of the PDFs generated have alignment issues. The issue is with the margin size. In the new environment, big margins are coming which is causing alignment issue. But all the reports do not have this issue only some RPT's that are export have them.The new environment where I have alignment issue do not have any printers. But the environments where the alignment is correct have printers. Dose RPT export in any way depend on printers installed in a machine

To find out what the margin size was I put system outs

iPrintOptions.getPageMargins().getLeft()+" ###### getRight:"iPrintOptions.getPageMargins().getRight() " ###### getTop:" iPrintOptions.getPageMargins().getTop() " ###### getBottom:" +iPrintOptions.getPageMargins().getBottom()

the result was getLeft(): 1440 ###### getRight:1440 ###### getTop:1440 ###### getBottom:1440

But when I system out margin values in the envionements where the PDFs are generated correctly the values are 360 , 360, 360, 360

I do not understand from where this 1440 value is coming from.

The margin configured for the RPT is .150 in,.250 in etc

Could you please help me resolve this alignment issues.

Thanks
Ann

Answer (score 0):

Try opening the report and going to file, page setup. Tick the "no printer (optimize for screen display)" option. Your problem SHOULD go away.